# How do i read multiple lines from a file into a string to put in jTextArea?

Tags: java, swing

ive tried many different things and this is the only thing that has worked with reading one line from a file so far...

```
try{

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("./Saves/Body.sav");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(infstream);
        String strLine;    
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {      
        System.out.println(strLine);
        w1.Body = strLine;
        }  
        in.close();
          }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

I am trying to create a load function so i can load text from a file onto a string onto a jTextArea... Without any sort of openfiledialog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd personally use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com):

```
File file = new File("Saves", "Body.sav");
String text = Files.toString(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

That's assuming it's a UTF-8 file, of course. Adjust accordingly.

Your current code has a number of issues:

- It creates a `DataInputStream` for no obvious reason
- You *probably* don't gain much from using `BufferedReader`
- You're not specifying the character encoding, so you're getting the platform default, implicitly, which is almost never a good idea.
- You're closing `in` which is in the middle of the chain of inputs for some reason... I'd expect to close either `br` or `fstream`
- You're only closing `in` if there's no exception (use a `finally` block or a try-with-resources statement if you're using Java 7)
- You appear to have a field called `Body`, violating Java naming conventions
- You're catching `Exception` rather than `IOException` - prefer to catch specific exceptions
- You're "handling" the exception by effectively ignoring it, which is almost *never* appropriate. (The code which reads a file is very rarely the right code to decide what to do with an exception.)

Comment: it looks like the asker is new to java and i feel that your answer does not really benefit him. maybe someone will stumble upon your answer in the future and find it useful.

Comment: @AlexLynch: I've added a bunch of things wrong with the existing code, but I feel that teaching a new user about a library which will help him avoid reinventing the wheel (badly) is probably the approach with the *most* benefit.

Comment: @JonSkeet this is no place to argue, but i feel it should be said: reinventing the wheel is important when the user needs to learn the fundamentals. look at all of those things you've pointed out to be wrong in his code - he will not understand why those are problems if he were to just accept your version of this hypothetical wheel. at least you have benefit the user by pointing out his errors now though, so i am satisfied.

Comment: @AlexLynch And one must tell a new Java developer about a lib such as Guava.

Answer (score 3):

> How do i read ... put in jTextArea?

Ignoring the entire middle of that statement, I suggest.

```
File file = new File("./Saves/Body.sav");
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
textArea.read(fileReader, file);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `StringBuilder` (or the synchronized version `StringBuffer`) and keep appending `strLine` to it. Declare it this way:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
```

and in the `while` loop:

```
s.append(strLine + "\n");
```

Comment: You *could* do this, certainly - but if you're just joining the lines together, it seems pointless to read line-by-line in the first place. It does canonicalize the line endings, I guess...